# Symfony 4 Service Injection Too Few Arguments

Tags: dependency-injection, symfony4

In my Symfony 4 project I've created a HelloBlock class in the /src/Blocks/Hello/HelloBlock.php file.

Here's its constructor...

```
public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
{
    $this->em = $entityManager;
}
```

And then in my services.yaml I've added this...

```
    App\Blocks\:
        resource: '../src/Blocks'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

When running my code (dev environment, cache cleared, etc) I'm getting the "Too few arguments" error. It's not injecting the dependency.

Can anyone help? I thought this is what the Symfony DI is supposed to do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### Missing arguments:

You probably have to provide the `arguments:` to the service definition.

```
App\Blocks\:
    resource: '../src/Blocks'
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
    arguments:
        - '@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager'
```

`@` is used to **not** interpret the name as a simple string but to fetch the actual service instead.

### Default Doctrine naming:

The naming is a little bit tricky; [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43042335/3088045) made me understand how the naming is built: *<entitymanager_name>* (according to the `doctrine.orm.entity_managers` YAML definition) concatenated to `_entity_manager`.

With the special case of the `default` one that is available as `doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager` even when not explicitly defined in the above mentioned config key.

#### My assumption:

I tried on my app to just add that string as an argument and it didn't fail. Then I put a typo, and it failed. So I assume that `default_entity_manager` is defined automatically (I am not sure where).

---

### Otherwise:

In case it doesn't work, the other fix would be to verify why the entityManager is  not automatically wired. Check your config for autowiring the `src/` folders.

```
App\:
    resource: '../src/*'
    exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Tests, ....}'
```

and ensure that `Blocks` is not listed among the `exclude` folders.

Comment: [This is another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52254378/3088045) where the needed definition of `arguments:` for 3rd party services is mentioned.