# Symfony 4: "Autowire: you should configure its value explicitly."

Tags: php, symfony4

I'm starting to working with Symfony4 and I meet the following error when I try to run my server: **Cannot autowire service "App\Controller\CharacterInformation": argument "$region" of method "__construct()" is type-hinted "string", you should configure its value explicitly.**

How I instantiate my class:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/")
 * @return Response
 */
function mainPage() {
    $characterInformation = new CharacterInformation('eu');
    return new Response($characterInformation->getCharacter());
}
```

The constructor of CharacterInformation:

```
 /**
 * @var int
 */
public function __construct(string $region) {
        $this->apiInformation = new ApiContent($region);
}
```

The constructor of ApiContent:

```
    public function __construct(string $region) {
    $apiToken = new ApiToken($region);
    $this->token = $apiToken->getToken();
    $this->region = $apiToken->getRegion();
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Try to set autowire information into **config/services.yaml**. Like:

```
#app.myservice.config:
    App\Controller\CharacterInformation:
        arguments:
            $region: "%region%"
```

Check all information into [Defining Services Dependencies Automatically (Autowiring)](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html#an-autowiring-example)

Comment: I did exactly that and nothing changed. I even tried to put that in _defaults.bind section

Comment: Hey @afilina , are you saw Karringan answer below?

Comment: Yes. That didn't help. In the end, I found out that my yaml file that was defining the service wasn't being loaded, therefore the string args didn't kick in.

Answer (score 4):

Also you can resolve this problem by binding parameters in your `services.yml` file.

Here is well explained https://stackoverflow.com/a/49084402

```yaml
    # config.yml
    parameters:
      foo: 'secret'

    services:
      _defaults:
         autowire: true
         bind:
           $fooKey: '%foo%'
```