# Dependency injection : Get Param in controller

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, symfony-3.4

I am in the process of migrating an application from Symfony 2.8 to Symfony 3.4

The services are now private and therefore instead of making a direct call to the services from the container, we must use dependency injection as a workaround.

For parameters, is **$this->getParameter()** is an anti pattern ? If yes, how can we get them in controller  and of course we must always respecting the good practices ?

For information, there is a solution in **Symfony 4.1**, using the **bind** in **services.yml**

This the following script and this the **environment** as an example :

```
class CmsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function importExportAction(Request $request): Response
    {
        $adminPool = $this->get('sonata.admin.pool');
        $env = $this->getParameter('environment');

         return new Response('OK');
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, you should consider your controllers as services. Then you only have to configure them in yaml files like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11211620/6410457)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controllers are now seen as services.

You can look at [this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11211620/6410457), to know how configure services with parameters.

Comment: Down voted because link only answers are discouraged.  It's also interesting that the answer linked dates back to 2016.  So the "now seen" part is a bit strange.  Controllers could always be configured as services though using the container as a service locator was the original recommended approach.