# Symfony3.4: Attempted to call an undefined method named "getParameter" of class "Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ServiceLocator"

Tags: php, symfony

In Symfony3.4, the following error occurred while supporting automatic wiring.
The following error occurs even if the container is removed, just changing the class.
I changed the controller to an abstract controller due to another error, so I want to use the abstract controller as much as possible.
Is there anything I have forgotten?

https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/service_container/3.3-di-changes.html

Error

```
Attempted to call an undefined method named "getParameter" of class "Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ServiceLocator".
```

Controller.php

```php
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class DefaultController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @param KeepRequestService $keepRequestService
     * @return array
     */
    private function getKeepRequestSummary(KeepRequestService $keepRequestService): array
    {
        $summary = array();
        
        //Error line        
        foreach (array_keys($this->container->getParameter('keep_request_status')) as $status) {

            $params = array('status' => $status);
            $summary[$status] = $keepRequestService->countKeepRequestBySearchParams($params);
        }
        return $summary;
    }
```

services.yml

```yaml
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false

    App\:
        resource: '../../src/*'
        exclude: '../../src/{Ahi/Sp/AdminBundle/Model/Entity, Ahi/Sp/AdminBundle/Model/Repository, Ahi/Sp/AdminBundle/Resources/public/uploadify, Ahi/Sp/AdminBundle/Ahi/Sp/PublicBundle/ }'

    App\Ahi\Sp\AdminBundle\Controller\:
        resource: '../../src/Ahi/Sp/AdminBundle/Controller'
        public: true
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

Comment: Did you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49084402/8411841 Injecting and using the container is now bad practice. Parameters and services should be injected instead.

Comment: @Vyctorya Thanks for your comment. Thanks to you, I was able to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Vyctorya advised, I modified the code as below and the code disappeared.

Controller.php

```php
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $keepRequestStatus;

    public function __construct(array $keepRequestStatus)
    {
        $this->keepRequestStatus = $keepRequestStatus;
    }
   private function getKeepRequestSummary(KeepRequestService $keepRequestService)
    {
        $summary = array();
        foreach (array_keys($this->keepRequestStatus) as $status) {
            $params = array('status' => $status);
            $summary[$status] = $keepRequestService->countKeepRequestBySearchParams($params);
        }
        return $summary;
    }
```

services.yml

```yaml
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false
        bind:
          $keepRequestStatus: '%keep_request_status%'
```